# undefined complexType in Sabre Passenger Details RQ

Tags: c#, sabre

When i convert wsdl link to c# soap api class using ReadyAPI i am getting this error

Passenger Details RQ
http://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/ServicesPlatform/PassengerDetails3.3.0RQ.wsdl

```
Schema validation error: Schema with targetNamespace='http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3' has invalid syntax. Undefined complexType 'http://services.sabre.com
/STL_Payload/v02_01:STL_Request_Payload' is used as a base for complex type extension. Line 8, position 6.
Schema validation error: Schema with targetNamespace='http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3' has invalid syntax. Undefined complexType 'http://services.sabre.com
/STL_Payload/v02_01:STL_Response_Payload' is used as a base for complex type extension. Line 12, position 6.
Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.
Warning: no classes were generated.
Warnings were encountered. Review generated source comments for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you import all of the common schemas locally? Have you tested the same in Visual Studio?

Comment: i am using ready api to convert wsdl to soap api.
yes i added all schemas